# $P(\max_{1 \leq p \leq k}|Y_p| >\epsilon) \geq 1-4\frac{(\epsilon+\max_{1 \leq p \leq k } |X_p-E[X_p]|)^2}{\operatorname{Var}(Y_k)}$

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

$(X_k)_k$ is a sequence of independent r.v uniformly bounded by $c.$ If $\sum_{k}X_k$ converges a.s then $\sum_{k}E[X_k]$ converges.

The above is proved using the following inequality ($X_k$ should be centered):
$$P\left(\max_{p \leq k}|Y_p|>\epsilon\right) \geq 1-\frac{(\epsilon+c)^2}{E[Y^2_k]} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1) $$ where $Y_k=\sum_{p=1}^kX_k.$

If $X_k$ are not centered then they consider independent copy of $X_k.$

***The objective is to find a way to solve the problem without the use of symmetric random variable***, after searching, the following inequality (it seems it's a generalization of $(1)$) seems to solve the problem: $$P\left(\max_{1 \leq p \leq k}|Y_p| >\epsilon\right) \geq 1-4\frac{(\epsilon+\max_{1 \leq p \leq k } |X_p-E[X_p]|)^2}{\operatorname{Var}(Y_k)} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

Once $(2)$ is proved we can see that $\max_{1 \leq p \leq k}|X_p-E[X_p]| \leq 2c$

How to prove $(2)$ ? (Of course the natural way to prove it is to consider $E_p:=\{|Y_1| \leq \epsilon,...,|Y_{p-1}| \leq \epsilon,|Y_p|>\epsilon\}$).

Any other inequalities to solve the problem are welcomed!

Comment: What is objectionable about symmetrization?

Comment: It seems you asked essentially the same question at the same time on math.stackexchange.com. Please don’t do this. It leads to a duplication of effort. This question is probably more suitable for this site, so you should probably delete the other one.

Comment: @IosifPinelis no objection! (We can also deduce the above theorem from the CLT...). So, it's just an interesting question, especially the inequality $(2)$!

Comment: Inequality (2) looks strange, with its right-hand side being a random variable.

Comment: After a long search, it turns out $(2)$ is taken from : https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01459098.pdf, unfortunately not in english, possibly in german (according to google translate)

Comment: I have added an extended comment concerning (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

> If $(X_k)$ is a sequence of independent r.v.'s uniformly bounded in absolute value by some real $c$ such that $\sum_{k}X_k$ converges a.s., then $\sum_{k}EX_k$ converges

follows almost immediately from the Hoffmann–Jørgensen inequality
$$EM^2\le2.4^2c^2+32t_0^2$$
(see e.g. [Proposition 6.8](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-20212-4)),
where $M:=\sup_k|S_k|$, $S_k:=\sum_{j=1}^k X_j$, and $t_0>0$ is such that $P(M>t_0)<1/32$. Indeed, since $S_\infty$ is finite a.s., we have $M<\infty$ a.s. and hence we can assume that $t_0<\infty$, so that $Var\, S_n\le ES_n^2\le EM^2\le2.4^2c^2+32t_0^2<\infty$ for all natural $n$.

Now Kolmogorov's [two-series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_two-series_theorem) implies that $\sum_k(X_k-EX_k)$ converges a.s. Since $\sum_k X_k$ converges a.s., we conclude that $\sum_k EX_k$ converges, as desired.

**Extended comment:** As the OP noted in a comment, inequality (2) does appear, as Satz III, in [Kolmogorov's paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01459098.pdf) (of 1928, in German). However, apparently there is a mistake in the proof of this inequality in that paper. Namely, with standard modern notations: $E$ in place of $\mathfrak D$ (the expectation symbol in that paper), $A_k$ in place of $\mathfrak f_k$ (a certain event), and $EX1_{A_k}$ in place of $\mathfrak D_{\mathfrak f_k}(X)$, the equality in line 10 on p. 312 of Kolmogorov's paper becomes
$$|t_k-Et_k1_{A_k}|=|s_k-Es_k1_{A_k}|,$$
which was apparently thought of as the consequence of the equality
$$t_k-Et_k1_{A_k}=s_k-Es_k1_{A_k};\tag{$*$}$$
here, according to p. 310 of Kolmogorov's paper, $t_k=s_k-Es_k$. However, actually
$$t_k-Et_k1_{A_k}=s_k-Es_k1_{A_k}-Es_k(1-P(A_k)).$$
So, ($*$) holds only if $Es_k=0$ or $P(A_k)=1$, which latter is not true in general. Thus, the proof seems to only work if $Es_k=0$ for all $k$. This is the first time in my life where I seem to see a mistake made by Kolmogorov!

It appears that this mistake was (tacitly?) corrected in later publications by symmetrization (which obviously provides for the zero-mean condition). If that correction was made indeed tacitly, it appears to be a disservice to people interested in this matter, as the question on this webpage shows.

Anyhow, the Hoffmann–Jørgensen inequality seems to be a more effective and more transparent way to achieve the desired result, as shown above in this answer.

Comment: After running a search on the above publication (google books), it appears that Kai Lai Chung (A course in probability theory, third edition) use inequality $(2)$ (the correct version) and he provided a proof (it's theorem 5.3.2)..

Comment: The funny thing is that inequality $(1)$ and the symmetric argument are asked in the exercises right after this section

Comment: @Kurt.W.X : I see "Finally, and this is mentioned here only in response to a query by Doob, I chose to present the brutal Theorem 5.3.2 in the original form given by Kolmogorov because I want to expose the student to hardships in mathematics."  on p.434 at https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=RJ0z-pwQvTkC&hl=en&pg=GBS.PR15 . Can you give me a link to the Google book by Chung? I cannot find it right away.

Comment: I can post a picture - pdf file for the page from Chung books (because in Google books - amazon... it only shows a preview for the book and it happens that the page from where theorem 5.3.2 is taken is not omitted)

Comment: Here's the link for google books: https://books.google.com.lb/books?id=zu80w7wd40UC&lpg=PA3&pg=PA123#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: pages 123-124 (theorem 5.3.2 and its proof)

Comment: I now see why Chung calls that theorem 'brutal". Unfortunately, he does not mention the mistake in Kolmogorov's proof. Anyhow, the Hoffmann–Jørgensen inequality seems more natural, more effective, and easier to prove.

Comment: A "variant" of Hoffmann–Jørgensen inequality can be also found https://www.amazon.com/Probability-Theory-Independence-Interchangeability-Martingales/dp/0387406077/ page 115, by introducing a stopping time